# Getting current contact record in Apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I am working in the Service Console. I have a VF page displayed as a component in the right side panel. I want to display all contacts related to the current contact based on a particular custom field value. It's a simply query. The problem is that I can't get the apex class to find the current contact record.

Here's my Apex class:

```
public class ConciergeDisplayFamilyMembers
{ 
public Contact currentContact {get;set;}

public List<Contact> Records
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            Records = new List<Contact>();
            Records = [SELECT Name,Gender__c,Subscriber_ID__c,Member_ID_suffix__c,Member_ID__c FROM Contact WHERE Subscriber_ID__c = :currentContact.Subscriber_ID__c AND RecordTypeId = '012q00000004SAiAAM']; 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
            Records = null;
            }
            return Records;
    }
    private set;
    }


public ConciergeDisplayFamilyMembers(ApexPages.StandardController sc)
{
    currentContact = (Contact) sc.getRecord();

}
```

Here's my VF page code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ConciergeDisplayFamilyMembers"> 
<apex:pageBlock > 
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Records}" var="Record"> 
        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!Record.Name}"/> 
        </apex:column> 
        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header">Member ID</apex:facet> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!Record.Member_ID__c}"/> 
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header">suffix</apex:facet> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!Record.Member_ID_suffix__c}"/> 
        </apex:column>  
        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header">Gender</apex:facet> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!Record.Gender__c}"/> 
        </apex:column> 
        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header">Subscriber ID</apex:facet> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!Record.Subscriber_ID__c}"/> 
        </apex:column> 
    </apex:pageBlockTable> 
</apex:pageBlock>
```

If I remove the part of the `WHERE` clause getting the `Subscriber_ID__c` (and just query based on `RecordType`), it does return the records I expect to see. But when I try to use the `Subscriber_ID__c`, it returns no records at all.

Any help as to why the apex code isn't returning anything (or the correct value?) when I use `:currentContact.Subscriber_ID__c` in the `WHERE` clause of the `SOQL` query is much appreciated!

Comment: One other thing: when I change the SOQL to Records = [SELECT Name,Gender__c,Subscriber_ID__c,Member_ID_suffix__c,Member_ID__c FROM Contact WHERE ID = :currentContact.ID]; it does return the current record's information and displays it on the VF page. But I can't use any value in the SOQL other than the ID.

Comment: Can you try to initialize the currentContact using a soql rather than getting from controller? like `currentContact = [select id, Subscriber_ID__c from contact where id = :sc.getRecord().id ]`. What I'm guessing may be that, when you get the contact record, you will have to initialize the fields you need.

Answer (score 1):

I called Salesforce support regarding this issue. Changing the Apex class as follows fixes the problem:

```
public class ConciergeDisplayFamilyMembers
{ 
public Contact currentContact {get;set;}     

public List<Contact> Records
{

    get
    {
        try
        {
            Records = new List<Contact>();
            Records = [SELECT Name,Gender__c,Subscriber_ID__c,Member_ID_suffix__c,Member_ID__c FROM Contact WHERE Subscriber_ID__c = :currentContact.Subscriber_ID__c and RecordTypeId = '012q00000004SAiAAM']; 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
              Records = null;
        }
        return Records;
    }
    private set;
}

public ConciergeDisplayFamilyMembers(ApexPages.StandardController sc)
   {
    sc.AddFields(new List<String>{'Subscriber_ID__c'});
    currentContact = (Contact) sc.getRecord();     
    System.debug('***** ' + currentContact );
   }
}
```

Comment: You are correct and that is exactly what I was going to say. With Controllers and VF fields that are not referenced not he vf page must be added like you did. There was a bug with it for test methods where it would error on the addFields part so watch out for that if it has not been resolved. Also you could simply add it to the VF page as an `output field` with `rendered=false` and accomplish the same thing (if you have issues with your test methods and the addFields)